# Django admin: 'bool' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: django

I am using django_smart_select package. I am getting the following error for the model in which I am trying to use the chained select option.

```
AttributeError at /admin/tags/tag/add/
'bool' object has no attribute 'startswith'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/tags/tag/add/
Django Version: 1.11.4
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'bool' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Error during template rendering

In template C:\Users\gautammandewalker\Envs\django01\lib\site-
packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\base.html, error at line 3
'bool' object has no attribute 'startswith'
1   {% load i18n static %}<!DOCTYPE html>
2   {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}{% get_current_language_bidi 
as LANGUAGE_BIDI %}
3   <html lang="{{ LANGUAGE_CODE|default:"en-us" }}" {% if LANGUAGE_BIDI 
%}dir="rtl"{% endif %}>
4   <head>
5   <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
6   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% block stylesheet %}{% 
static "admin/css/base.css" %}{% endblock %}" />
7   {% block extrastyle %}{% endblock %}
8   {% if LANGUAGE_BIDI %}<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% 
block stylesheet_rtl %}{% static "admin/css/rtl.css" %}{% endblock %}" />{% 
endif %}
9   {% block extrahead %}{% endblock %}
10  {% block blockbots %}<meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE" />{% 
 endblock %}
11  </head>
12  {% load i18n %}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is preferred if you can post your code. That way, it helps the people answering your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use in `settings.py`:

```
USE_DJANGO_JQUERY = True
```

Remove

```
JQUERY_URL = True
```

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem.

Remove from `settings.py`:

```
SMART_SELECTS_JQUERY_URL = True
JQUERY_URL = True
```

Whichever you are using.

Instead of them add scripts directly to templates of the pages when you are using smart-selects forms:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'smart-selects/admin/js/bindfields.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'smart-selects/admin/js/chainedfk.js' %}"></script>
```

jQuery from smart-selects have to be interfering with admin page somehow.

Comment: So, if I am using smart-selcts only in admin, there is no need of adding JQUERY_URL = True in the settings.py file.

Comment: For me it was unnecessary. If it does not work you may have to overwrite admin page form template with attached scripts.

Comment: OK. I will try this today.

Comment: @AfroMetal, how do you know which admin page to overwrite?

Answer (score 0):

This is jQuery binding issue, Jet uses Django jQuery while Smart Select uses Google API by default.

Just simply for Smart Select in your Django settings place the following:

```
JQUERY_URL = False
```